# Using tinymce imagemanager.browse, how do I change the field names dynamically using jQuery

Tags: jquery, tinymce, mcimagemanager

I'm using mcImageManager.browse to select an image, everything works accordingly. I want to allow the user to be able to add multiple images, so I have used a plus icon beside the input and this creates a clone of the mcImagemanager.browse field and adds it to the page. I am having trouble changing the information within the .browse function.

```
onclick="mcImageManager.browse({fields : 'images1', relative_urls : true, document_base_url : '/uploads/images/'})
```

I want to simply change the 'fields' field to use images2. How do I change this value and set the content to be blank?

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have been wrecking my brain for days now on forums trying to find an answer.